# Merging Observables in Reactive Extensions?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Just learning RX and wanted to make a program that iterated the file system. Here is what I came up with that works:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static IObservable<string> GetFiles(string folder, string filePattern)
        {
            return Observable.Create<string>(
                o =>
                {
                    var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, filePattern);

                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        o.OnNext(file);
                    }

                    var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(folder);

                    foreach (var f in folders)
                    {
                        var x = GetFiles(f, filePattern);
                        x.Subscribe(p => { o.OnNext(p); });
                    }

                    o.OnCompleted();

                    return Disposable.Empty;
                });
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var o = GetFiles(@"d:\temp", "*.*");

            o.Subscribe(p => { Console.WriteLine(p); });

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

(Note the use of recursion by calling GetFiles again and subscribing)

While it works it seems very clumsy, I can't help thinking that I should be using something like Concat to combine the sequences instead of just bubbling them back up.

Also I would like to change that Foreach to a Parallel.ForEach but I'm unsure the ramifications this would have using RX. I can't seem to find much for documentation.

Any tips on how to write this better using RX?

Comment: Wow can't believe I never knew you could use this instead:
var files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, filePattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
Simplifies things quite a bit. Original questions still apply though.

Comment: Reading files from the file system is essentially an enumeration - as evidenced by the solution at which you arrived. Because of this, it's not really a good example from which to learn Rx. It isn't very "reactive". Better would be to create an observable that produced an event whenever a file is added to a directory. The events of the `FileSystemWatcher` combined with `Observable.FromEventPattern` could be a starting point for this.

Comment: Good advice. I was just looking for something to try with RX, I'll give you suggestion a go. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve a problem like this, it can help to write a LINQ version of the function first.  eg:

```
    static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string folder, string filePattern)
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(folder, filePattern)
            .Concat(Directory.GetDirectories(folder).SelectMany(f => GetFilesEnumerable(f, filePattern)));
    }
```

Then just change the IEnumerables to IObservables:

```
    static IObservable<string> GetFiles(string folder, string filePattern)
    {
        return Directory.GetFiles(folder, filePattern).ToObservable()
            .Concat(Directory.GetDirectories(folder).ToObservable().SelectMany(f => GetFilesEnumerable(f, filePattern)));
    }
```

Comment: Very nice way to think about it. Answers the original question better then mine so marked as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, based on my discovery of SearchOption.AllDirectories (why in all my years have I never noticed this) it can be boiled down into two real lines of code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var o = Directory.GetFiles(@"e:\code", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToObservable();
            o.Subscribe(f => Console.WriteLine(f));


            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Crazy how simple it really is now. Need a new RX problem to play with.